# The wide range of suction cups

Tags: robotic-arm

I noticed that there are heaps of suction cup types for vacuum arms, but how to tell which cup type should be used when? The way I read it is, for bigger and heavier objects, a cup with a large membrane should be used. But what about those with various patterns, e.g., ones with the Labyrinth patterns?

[image]
[image]

Comment: the labyrinth prevents flimsy material, like paper, from getting sucked into the vacuum port and getting crinkled

Comment: @jsotola Makes sense. In that case, why isn't the labyrinth used for all objects?

Comment: Like the answer to many engineering questions. Money.

Comment: also, the labyrinth channels can trap dirt